# Understanding android:layout_weight

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-layout-weight

Why the following listing shows only the second `TextView` (red)?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="11111"
        android:background="#00FF00" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="00000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know that if I set `android:layout_height="0px"` it will only show the first `TextView` (green), and I understand this behavior.

But why when I set `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, the first `TextView` disappear completely from the screen.

Comment: The weighted dimension **must** be **0dp**, for all the weighted Views. And weighting one View to **1** and the other one to **0** is not a good idea. Use `android:visibility="GONE"`, to hide a View

Comment: Try to see this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Answer (score 4):

From https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

It disappers because it second one acquires full space as it is given

`android:layout_weight="0"`

and

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`** as mentioned in above link.

> LinearLayout also supports assigning a weight to individual children
>   with the `android:layout_weight` attribute. This attribute assigns an
>   "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should
>   occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to
>   fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a
>   weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is
>   assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight.
>   **Default weight is zero**.
>
> **For example**, if there are three text fields and two of them declare a
>   weight of 1, while the other is given no weight, **the third text field
>   without weight will not grow and will only occupy the area required by
>   its content.** The other two will expand equally to fill the space
>   remaining after all three fields are measured.
>
> **If the third field is then given a weight of 2 (instead of 0), then it
>   is now declared more important than both the others**, so it gets half
>   the total remaining space, while the first two share the rest equally.

Answer (score 1):

`android:layout_weight="1"`  means you are assigning the remaining space which is not occupied by other views to that view.. so here in your case **second** `TextView` is match_parent so no space is left blank thats why **first** `TextView` is not visible

P.S: Pass weightsum to the parent layout and distribute that weight among child Views according to your need.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically saying,  give my first text view all the space and my second text view none, try  giving the children each a weight of 1, this should give them equal spacing. Also as you have a vertical oriented parent, setting the layout height in the children to match the parent is contradicting to the weight attribute. So remove it and replace with wrap content.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="11111"
    android:background="#00FF00" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:text="00000"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wrap content will wrap around your text, it would be usefull to add an atttribute for the size of text

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_weight means how u want these views to be showed comparing to each other and the parent view
for exampel, if u these codes:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button2"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[the result will be this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmXtW.jpg)

if i change android:layout_weight of Button1 from 1 to 2 while Button2's weight is still 1, then Button1's Width will be 2times bigger than Button2's

Answer (score 0):

You have set the weight value of the first button to 1 and the second to 0,
 so button one will cover the whole space

You should give a weight total to the parent layout and distribute the total between the children according to the desired proportion.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

https://ugia.io/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/

match_parent is different from wrap_content or specific sizes(0px, 1px, 100px etc.), it will take all space of parent view till the size of LinearLayout in your case.

layout_weight is for balancing, and it depends on your layout_width

Answer (score 0):

But why, if I set in the second TextView:

```
android: layout_weight = "0.1"
```

the second component of the TextView will take less space than if I set:

```
android: layout_weight = "0"
```

And if I set in the second TextView

```
android: layout_weight = "0.2"
```

the second component of the TextView will take even less space than  if I set

android: layout_weight = "0.1"

So if I set higher the value of android:layout_weight, that it occupies a smaller size.